# Why trying to go to a TLD results in `dns_server_failure` instead of `dns_unresolved_hostname`?

Tags: dns

When I try to go to a TLD, I get a `dns_server_failure`. Why do I get this error instead of `dns_unresolved_hostname`? Examples are:

`http://com.`

`http://net.`

`http://asdfasdfasdfasdasdfasdfasdf.`

etc.

Comment: You'll need to describe more about your network and test setup, I'm getting a proper, immediate NXDOMAIN answer for all of these.

Comment: I am at work and not in network department. Hence, I don't know very much about my network setup but I know that traffic is being sent to a proxy server. For the rest, I guess we have to speculate.

Comment: Oh and I am testing these in a web browser.

Comment: I don't think there is much we can achieve by speculation, something in the proxy setup doesn't handle TLDs well. Possibly by not interpreting the '.' at the end correctly or having an outdated list of top level DNS servers or not having direct access to top level servers from within DMZ or any other reason.